# i want to pass value from another datatable

Tags: c#

I am having one `datatable` to that table i want to pass value from another `datatable`.

> for example:-

datatable1 in this
i want to pass value from
`datatable2.row[0]["colname"]`

> i tried like :-

`tblvdr.Rows[0]["item_Vendorname"] = dttemp.Rows[0]["item_Vendorname"];`

> error message:-

its showing error for No row at o position

Comment: First check datatable2 has sufficient rows to get value from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DataRow tblvdrRow = tblvdr.NewRow();
 tblvdrRow["item_Vendorname"]= dttemp.Rows[0]["item_Vendorname"];
 tblvdr.Rows.Add(tblvdrRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data table `tblvrd` does not have any row. For this use

```
 DataRow newRow = tblvdr.NewRow();
```

One tme a new row is generated you can populate it from the row in another table. Naturally you need generate new row in `tblvdr` for every row in `dttemp`